# How to house-rule re-locking a door using a lockpick?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, house-rules

It is apparently possible (in real life) to [lock a lock using lockpicks](http://www.lockpicking101.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=48889):

> ## Locking locks
>
> <sup>by rgsupergrover » Tue Aug 24, 2010 11:48 am</sup>
>
> Sorry in advance since this may be a very ameture question, but can you lock a lock with a set of picks?
>   I have tried a couple of times, but no success.
>
> ---
>
> ### Re: Locking locks
>
> <sup>by Solomon » Tue Aug 24, 2010 5:09 pm</sup>
>
> Course you can. It's exactly the same as opening, you're doing the same thing. I assume you're working on either euro cylinders or mortice lever locks?

But (not surprisingly) D&D 3.5e doesn't provide any rules for this unusual task.

What should the process (and DC) for doing this be? Since it's apparently the "same thing" as unlocking with lockpicks it shouldn't be that different, but it's obviously a less-practiced process for the average roguish type. Should it just be the same rules as picking locks? If so, should it use the same DC, or a different one?

(Before anyone gets into arguments about why anyone would bother when you could just lock the door before shutting it: deadbolt locks can't be locked before closing a door, and locks on chests similarly can only be locked from outside.)

Comment: A reminder that [per meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5153/1204), **homebrew answers should come from experience** in order to be reliable and satisfy [good subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). You should have tried this in your own game or witnessed it happening, and be able to talk about how it worked out. Naturally a lot of us could come up with something on the spot, but having actually tried it makes the difference for whether it will work *well.*

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Baseline: DC of the lock.
Add modifiers where appropriate, e.g.:

- Padlock that needs to be held closed while picking: +5
- In the dark: +0
- From inside chest (very awkward): +10-+20
- Big troll pushing on the other side of the door: +5 for stress, +a lot if no one else is keeping the door closed
- etc.

Comment: This might be the start of a good answer. It provides only *suggestions* though, without any support for *why* the specifics suggested are worth adopting. Since anyone can just make up a house rule for a situation, the quality of the "why" separates the good answers from the "huh?" answers.

Comment: For reference, the "why" is that the process of picking a barrel lock is one of shifting the pins into the correct positions so that the barrel can be turned. This process is exactly the same regardless of whether the lock's barrel starts in the "open" or "closed" position, so the difficulty shouldn't change. (Of course, if you've picked a particular lock while opening it, you should presumably have an easier time picking it while closing it, as you've already picked the lock once before.)

Comment: @GMJoe Which might be what Oldtimer was thinking, or might not. Even so, though, the salad of modifiers needs "whys" too, for why those numbers, and why those situations specifically.

Answer (score 5):

The question I would ask myself is, "Does it add anything to my game to have additional complexity here?" In my game, whenever someone wants to do anything to a lock - lock, unlock, jam it, etc., I see no reason why I should make things more complicated than an Open Locks roll against the lock's standard DC. (Though in the jamming it case, obviously if the person has Disable Device that DC 10 check will be a lot easier...)

Unless you are running a detailed rogue-intensive campaign, or an old school dungeon crawling campaign where locks and traps have a lot of additional resolution desired - then I'd add more details of that sort. But if this is just a routine thing and not really the core of what your campaign is about, adding complexity besides the already-complex 3.5e skill rules has a poor return on investment.

Answer (score 2):

When your quoted source says they're doing "the same thing" to lock a lock as to unlock it, they mean it's *exactly* the same thing. Literally the only thing that changes is the direction you push on the "wrench" (one of the picks), which is clockwise in one case and counterclockwise in the other, but is likewise reversed if you go to another lock that's designed to have the key turned the other direction. Therefore, both the simplest solution, *and the most realistic one*, is to just replace all instances of "unlock" in the skill description with "engage/disengage", and call it a day.